# how to shorten a very long code or replace a short code (performing the same function) with code?

Tags: android-studio, fragment, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav, android-bottomappbar

how shortening this code? because this code very long :'(

this code for bottom button navigation bar, javaclass fragment

please help me, I need to shorten this long code:

```
package com.this.program;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link YangiliklarFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class YangiliklarFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public YangiliklarFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment YangiliklarFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static YangiliklarFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        YangiliklarFragment fragment = new YangiliklarFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yangiliklar, container, false);
    }
}
```

only the function should not change.

thank you for help!

Tegs: Fragment, Bottom, Button, Navigation, Short, Long, Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the shortest i can...

```
package com.this.program;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class YangiliklarFragment extends Fragment {

    public YangiliklarFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yangiliklar, container, false);
        // your code...
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: are the functions of these codes the same?

Comment: Basically yes, you don't need the rest of the code...